# Retrieving values from browser cache

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I've created a service worker that performs a fetch and then immediately stores the data in the cache.

```
self.addEventListener('install', async function(e) {
    try {
        const fileCache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        await fileCache.addAll(FILES_TO_CACHE);
        const dataCache = await caches.open(DATA_CACHE_NAME);
        const dataFetchResponse = await fetch('/api/transaction');
        return await dataCache.put('/api/transaction', dataFetchResponse);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

After performing this I'm trying to make it so that I can test how long it's been since the last data fetch in order to determine if the data needs to be updated. My `Transaction` model adds a timestamp onto the data so I'd ideally want to test the timestamp of the last transaction against the current time but I'm not sure how to do it.

I've attempted to do `cache.match()` but it doesn't return the entire object of the matched key. I know localStorage has a `.getItem()` method but I don't see any methods for `cache` that are similar.

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: What does `cache.match()` return?

Comment: It'll return a matched value in the cache but so far the examples I've seen only match the key and not the value.

Comment: But that returned value doesn't contain the timestamp you want to know?

Comment: The examples I've seen will only return the key's value aka it's name and not the values contained within it.

Comment: Could you console.log it? `caches.match` searches in all caches and `cache.match()` in a specific catch. It must return the cached value, that's how service workers work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to get the information. You have to `.match()` the `key` of the data stored in the cache and since it returns a promise you convert that into a `.json()` object.

```
async function getCachedData(cacheName, url) {
    const cacheStorage = await caches.open(cacheName);
    const cachedResponse = await cacheStorage.match(url); // Returns a promise w/ matched cache
    if(!cachedResponse || !cachedResponse.ok) {return false}
    console.log(await cachedResponse);
    console.log(await cachedResponse.json()); // prints json object with value of key matched
    return await cachedResponse.json();
};
```